# How to make POST request with JSON data from PHP to Java?

Tags: java, php, json, curl

I have an application run on PHP. Now, I got a requirement where I have to send a API request (POST method) to a server which runs on JAVA including a json data. I tried to use curl method of php but was not able to send the request. I tried the below code for the same.

```
$data = array("user_id"=>"6cdedfcc-ff55-449f-8362-af3ae0e04928");
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                               

$ch = curl_init('https://java-api-url/api');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: What does mean 'unable to send request'? What response do you see after sending the POST-request?

Comment: Actually, when I checked the error with status code, I found that the issue was due to ssl certificate (https). The code was working as expected. Now, the issue is fixed. Thanks every one for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = NULL;

$data['user_id'] = "6cdedfcc-ff55-449f-8362-af3ae0e04928";

$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                               

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://java-api-url/api');                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);



print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

instead of:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");